# How to fix Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `User' using BCrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a sign in page using the gem BCript. 
Every thing was fine until this error hit me. I've checked all the project and stil dont understand where is the error coming from, I am almost sure that is not from the method create in UsersController. But I see no error elsewhere. 
Error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `User' for #<User:0x0000000007c7f720>
```

Using these parameters:

```
Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"Up3fTyw3rT6aNWgcg3eIUVsw8tboFmjbtQcdYDxUYobFiBnG3USB4aiIhqOYLkYafWykoYJupOzMxAGkxLLY3A==",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"nome", "email"=>"nome@nome.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Cadastrar"}
```

After trying to create a new user, in view/user/new.

```
   <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <div class="alert-error">
                O formulário contém <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "erro") %>.
            </div>
            <ul>
                <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Cadastrar"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the users controller:

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Usuário foi criado com sucesso!"
      sign_in(@user)
    else 
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

And here the sessions controller:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :block_access, except: [:destroy]

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

And aplication controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
include SessionsHelper
```

end

and sessions helper

```
module SessionsHelper
def sign_in
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

def block_access
    if current_user.present?
        redirect_to users_path
    end
end

def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
end
```

end

nothing in users helper

```
module UsersHelper
end
```

I'm using the following routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  resources :users
  get    'sign_in'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'sign_in'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'sign_out'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  root 'sessions#new'
end
```

my model:

```
   class User < ApplicationRecord
        has_secure_password
        validates name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
        validates password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
        VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
        validates email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 260 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
        before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    end
```

User class:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    validates name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
    validates email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 260 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
end
```

View/users/new:

```
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <div class="alert-error">
                O formulário contém <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "erro") %>.
            </div>
            <ul>
                <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Cadastrar"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

view/users/show:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h3>Perfil de <%= @user.name %> </h3>
    <%= @user.email %>
</body>
```

View/users/index:

```
    <h1> Users </h1>
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= user.name %></td>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "Show", user %></td>
        </tr>
     <%end%>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

View/session/new

```
    <%= form_for :session, url: sign_in_path do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", new_user_path %></p>
<% end %>
```

layouts/_head

```
    <header>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", sign_out_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", root_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Full page error:

Someone has any idea how to fix this?
fullpage error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vheAh.jpg

Comment: Could you provide your error call stack? Also, did you try to switch positions of redirect_to and sign_in? I suppose you need to first sign in the user and then redirect.

Comment: NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `User' for #<User:0x000000000b544dd0>
Extracted source (around line #17):
15
16
17
18
19
20
              
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Usuário foi criado com sucesso!"
    else

Comment: well, yes, it makes sense sing_in to come first, I've tried this, but it didnt work yet. Same error mensage.

Comment: Can you please paste full stack on your question? We need to see the files call stack as well.

Comment: Ok, but how can I do that here? I've added a full page screen screen capture of the error.

Comment: This is caused by something that's not visible in the code you provided. You can try to "byebug" this line of code and check @user object actually is. This could be one of your validations as well.

Comment: ok, almost everything is up now, including model validators. @user seems right, look at this:  "user"=>{"name"=>"nome", "email"=>"nome@nome.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Cadastrar"

Answer (score 0):

isn't it because you are trying to call sign_in()-method even after redirecting?
call redirect_to at the end of statement:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    sign_in(@user)
    redirect_to @user, notice: "Usuário foi criado com sucesso!"
  else 
  ...
```

Comment: this maks sense, but it seems is not yet the reason. I've changed the order, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user to the sign_in method:

```
def sign_in user
  session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

On your controller you are calling it like this:

```
sign_in @user
```